# Can i 'find' my pc via browser by typing in the name without editing the host file

Tags: javascript, activex, host

I have 2 PCs on my network.

Both are assigned DHCP address.

PC 1 is called 'test'.
PC 1 has IIS installed and can server asp.net pages

On PC 2 I open up a browser. If I type in 'test' I will not get the home page from PC 1 display.

I assume to accomplish that I would need to add an entry in the hosts file in both PC 1 and PC 2?

If so, that would not be viable for my Users.

If I created an ActiveX control to get the IP address it would only work in IE.

Can I use Javascript to return the IP for a given PC name?

What are my options if any?

Comment: Unless you have [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) you will not be able to resolve names to IP addresses without specifying them in your hosts files.

Comment: @PM77-1 thanks for taking the time to respond. I had v strong feeling this could not be done. I will just have to create a client app in c#. Thanks